# Is it possible to adjust width on date picker control in React office UI fabric

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

Having issues using the DatePicker control and fixing width for my SPFX app. The default width is 100%. I want it to be the same width as my text input, which I pass in a 700px width property into the `styles` parameter. There is no width or styles parameter I can pass in a prop to on the DatePicker component.

```
            <DatePicker label="Due Date"
                    value={this.state.Due_x0020_Date? new Date(): null}
                    onSelectDate = {(date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
                        this.state.Due_x0020_Date=date;  }}
                    disabled={this.state.mode === 'edit' ? true : false }
                    
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<DatePicker styles={{ root: {width: 700} }} />
```

Tested on Fluent `8.49.1`.

I suppose that your original code was missing the `root` key.

Citing docs:

**styles prop**

> A component consists of DOM elements, or "areas." Each of the areas should be targetable for styling.

> To find the available areas for a component, use intellisense or look at the IComponentStyles interface in the component's Component.types.ts file (substituting the actual component name for "Component").

Further reading - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web/colors/theme-slots.